# Expect item in array

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, promise, protractor

One of my test expects an error message text to be one of multiple values. Since *`getText()` returns a promise* I cannot use `toContain()` jasmine matcher. The following would not work since `protractor` (`jasminewd` under-the-hood) would not resolve a promise in the second part of the matcher, `toContain()` in this case:

```
expect(["Unknown Error", "Connection Error"]).toContain(page.errorMessage.getText());
```

**Question:** Is there a way to check if an element is in an array with jasmine+protractor where an element is a promise?

In other words, I'm looking for inverse of `toContain()` so that the `expect()` would implicitly resolve the promise passed in.

---

As a workaround, I can explicitly resolve the promise with `then()`:

```
page.errorMessage.getText().then(function (text) {
    expect(["Unknown Error", "Connection Error"]).toContain(text);
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the best option. I would also be okay with a solution based on third-parties like [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers).

---

As an example, this kind of assertion exists in Python:

```
self.assertIn(1, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Use `chai-as-promised`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if you could elaborate the suggestion into an answer with an example - would be great, since it sounds like a good legitimate alternative option to a custom matcher. Thank you!

Comment: In general I don't like offering libraries as answers to questions since that makes the questions library-recommendations - that said I think that in fact it's probably the best alternative in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you need a custom matcher. Depending on the version of Jasmine you are using:

**With Jasmine 1:**

```
this.addMatchers({
    toBeIn: function(expected) {
        var possibilities = Array.isArray(expected) ? expected : [expected];
        return possibilities.indexOf(this.actual) > -1;
    }
});
```

**With Jasmine 2:**

```
this.addMatchers({
    toBeIn: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return {
            compare: function(actual, expected) {
                var possibilities = Array.isArray(expected) ? expected : [expected];
                var passed = possibilities.indexOf(actual) > -1;

                return {
                    pass: passed,
                    message: 'Expected [' + possibilities.join(', ') + ']' + (passed ? ' not' : '') + ' to contain ' + actual
                };
            }
        };
    }
});
```

You'll have to execute this in the `beforeEach` section on each of your `describe` blocks it's going to be used in.

Your expect would look like:

```
expect(page.errorMessage.getText()).toBeIn(["Unknown Error", "Connection Error"]);
```

Answer (score 7):

The alternative solution is to use `.toMatch()` matcher with [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and specifically a special character `|` (called *"or"*), which allows to match only one entry to succeed:

```
expect(page.errorMessage.getText()).toMatch(/Unknown Error|Connection Error/);
```

Answer (score 3):

To me, the ***work-around*** that you identified is the best solution. However, we should not forget that this is an ***asynchronous execution*** and you might want to consider [Jasmine's asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

Then, your test will look like the following one:

```
it('should check item is in array', function(done){ //Note the argument for callback

    // do your stuff/prerequisites for the spec here

    page.errorMessage.getText().then(function (text) {
        expect(["Unknown Error", "Connection Error"]).toContain(text);
        done(); // Spec is done! 
    });
});
```

**Note:** If you don't pass this `done` argument to the `spec callback`, it is going to run to completion without failures, but no assertions are going to be reported in the execution results for that spec (in other words, that spec will have `0` assertions) and it might lead to confusions.