# Protractor - A/B Testing - Is it possible to expect 2 conditions by OR?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, ab-testing

I've A/B Test on some action and sometimes it registers to page A and sometimes to page B.

Is there any option to set 2 conditions for "expect" test?

Something like:

```
expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://wwww.pageA.com' || 'https://www.pageB.com');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expect item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747161/expect-item-in-array)

Comment: Thanks, something like: var expectConditions = ["www.a.com", "www.b.com"] ?

Comment: Yeah, if one of the array items matches an actual value, then you'll get your test passed. (considering that you use one of the methods from the duplicate question)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this, and it works..

```
var currentURL = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();

var pageA = 'https://wwww.pageA.com';
var pageB = 'https://www.pageB.com';

expect(currentURL == pageA || currentURL == pageB).toEqual(true, 'Not Matching!');
```