# Multiple Conditions in one expect

Tags: protractor

I want to Verify text of  AssignedAllUsers  List can contains test1 or test2 but it should not contain test3

I am using following but not sure what is the problem with the code I am getting following error : `AllAssignee.toContain is not a function`

```
 this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater("incident in $ctrl.allIncidents"));

 this.AssignedAllUsers = this.IncList.all(by.css('[aria-label="Change assignee to "]'));


AssignedAllUsers.getText().then(function(AllAssignee){
                        console.log("AllAssignee = "+AllAssignee);
                        expect((AllAssignee.toContain(Logindata.Username0)) || (AllAssignee.toContain(Logindata.Username1)) && (AllAssignee.not.toContain(Logindata.Username2)));
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a syntax issue.  `toContain` belongs outside the value being tested, in other words outside of the first set of parentheses following your `expect` statement.

You have this: 
`expect((AllAssignee.toContain(Logindata.Username0))`.  You also have an extra set of parentheses, though I don't think that really matters.

You need to close the `AllAssignee` call, it should be: `expect(AllAssignee).toContain(Logindata.Username0)`

To answer your other question, there's no need to do it in one `expect` statement really.  Since the list should never contain test3, thats your first assertion:
`expect(AllAssignee).not.toContain(test3);`

As for your other expected values, if you do not know which one will be present, just create an array and put both possible values inside of that.  Then you can assert against the array to contain either test1 or test2:

```
var myArray = ['test1', 'test2'];
expect(myArray).toContain(AllAssignee);
```

Also see this related question about [expecting items items in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747161/expect-item-in-array)

Answer (score -2):

Able to fix the problem with the code:
`expect(AllAssignee).toContain('test1' || 'test2');`

Comment: This is wrong and very misleading
the value simply translates to 'test2'

Comment: @David actually to `test1`